# Adding a see through/hole effect to a div with a png?

Tags: css, html, png

When you click the `#video_background` or `#nav` div `#infowrap` fades in. What I would like but I find almost impossible is to keep the exact same layout I have now for `#infowrap` but in the lower right corner punch a "hole" through the div so you could see the `#video_background` through that hole. I have looked into putting a png down there in a separate div or maybe put a png as a background but I just can't get it to work. Any ideas? This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content=""/>
        <meta name="keywords"content=""/>
        <title></title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body>
<header>
            <div id="nav">
                <p><a id="btn" href="#">+</a></p>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="infowrap">
                <div class="mainwrap">

                    <div class="smallwrap">
                        <p>Mustache art party pug whatever mixtape, pork belly sriracha gentrify swag. Try-hard selvage butcher high life, hashtag DIY ennui.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="smallwrap">
                        <p>Mustache art party pug whatever mixtape, pork belly sriracha gentrify swag. Try-hard selvage butcher high life, hashtag DIY ennui.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="smallwrap">
                        <p>Mustache art party pug whatever mixtape, pork belly sriracha gentrify swag. Try-hard selvage butcher high life, hashtag DIY ennui.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="smallwrap">
                        <p>Mustache art party pug whatever mixtape, pork belly sriracha gentrify swag. Try-hard selvage butcher high life, hashtag DIY ennui.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<video id="video_background" src="vid/147000037.mp4" autoplay loop>
<script>
                $('#video_background, #btn').on('click', function(){
                    $('#nav').toggleClass('rotate');
                });
        </script>




        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#video_background, #nav").click(function(){
            $("#infowrap").fadeToggle(250);
          });
        });
        </script>
    </body>






</html>
```

My css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight","HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

header {
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    color: #000000;
}

#nav {

    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: 15px;
    right: 25px;
    color: #000000;
}

#video_background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1000;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#infowrap {
    background: rgba(25,250,255,0.96);
    z-index: 900;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top:10px;left:10px;right:10px;bottom:10px;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.mainwrap {
    width: 540px;
    height: 540px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

.smallwrap {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: can you set up a jsFiddle or jsBin to show us what you are running into?

Comment: You're using an invalid structure for your HTML -- `<header>` should be inside your `<body>`. Actually, the `<video>` and `<script>` tags should also be in the `<body>`. Made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbjf8/) with the above code working (reordered tags)

Comment: Thank you. I edited the structure and added a background color to #infowrap. I want to punch a whole through the #infowrap.

Comment: If I understand well, it's same effect like if you change z-index on #video_background from -1000 to 1000?

Comment: I want to keep the video in the back at -1000. I just want to mask a hole in #infowrap so I can see the video playing through that hole.